# Unable to create ipa in xcode 6?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode6, provisioning-profile

I'm building an iOS app using storyboards.I have transfer my project to another mac.

When I'm creating a ipa, organiser screen opens and I selected export and then saved for ad-hoc deployment, but I'm getting an error as shown below.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

I tried to import all provisioning files again but its not working.I'm unable to handle this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to export your distribution certificate from your first machine to second machine. Then install ad hoc provisioning profile on second machine.

Comment: i have created distribution certificate again from my account and already added into the project

Comment: have you created certificate from same machine on which you are trying to make build.

Comment: No,created from another machine

Comment: that is what I have said in answer, you need to export your distribution certificate from machine on which you have created it. You can export it from keychain, just right click on certificate and export it in .p12 format then transfer that .p12 to machine on which you want to make build and install. Also install provisioning profile on that machine on which you want to make build.

Comment: @AshishP. i don't have second machine,now how i can solve this issue