# Exporting iOS distribution certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, ad-hoc-distribution

I created distribution certificate on one machine and I want to now run App on another machine. Only solution I found is to export and then import distribution certificate ([Unable to create ipa in xcode 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27378854/unable-to-create-ipa-in-xcode-6)).

But currently I don't have access to my first machine. Is there any alternate way? May be to export from developer.apple.com. IF not then why apple is not giving that flexibility?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can download them from [developer.apple.com](http://www.developer.apple.com) and import them.
2. Xcode has also the ability to sign in into your account and
   re-download them.

Here are steps that need to be followed for #2:

1. Go to Xcode;
2. Select "Preferences";
3. Choose "Account".

Answer (score 0):

If you requested the distribution certificate from one machine, then that is the only place that private key exists. The only options are to export the complete certificate (private and public keys) from that machine, or to create a new distribution certificate.

You can download the certificate from Apple as Ahmed mentioned above, but it will not contain the private key needed to sign your app.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to use a certificate without the private key. This key is only available on your previous machine.

You need this private key to sign the ipa through xcode.

The only options for you is to generate new certificate and provisioning profile (if you do not have access to previous machine).